# pub upgrade command still failing after 10 tries

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

1.Error: Error when reading

```
    '/C:/languages/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/.dart_tool/package_config.json': The system cannot find the path specified
C:/languages/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot: Error: Error when reading '/C:/languages/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am trying for flutter doctor and the following error was shown

```
Running pub upgrade...
Because flutter_tools depends on shelf 1.4.0 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (1 tries left)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go inside flutter SDK

You have to delete the **cache** folder inside bin and it will help you.